# Play 2 deploy on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to deploy my Play 2 website to a Ubuntu machine.

I'm running this on Mac OS X 10.10: `./activator debian:packageBin`

My build.sbt is:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import NativePackagerKeys._

name := """myapp"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.4.2",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype" % "jackson-datatype-joda" % "2.5.1"
)

// Don't include API documentation when packaging:
doc in Compile <<= target.map(_ / "none")


maintainer in Linux := "Me <me@example.com>"

packageSummary in Linux := "summary"

packageDescription := "description"

// We need this to be able to build a Debian package on non-Debian systems:
packageBin in Debian <<= debianJDebPackaging in Debian
```

When I install the generated package on the Ubuntu machine it seems to be running, but my site is not reachable on port 80 or 9000.
The logs (/var/log/myapp) are empty. Actually, the directory doesn't even exist.

When I sudo run the /usr/share/myapp/bin/myapp script manually I get errors:

> 15:38:33,899 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] -
>   Failed to create parent directories for
>   [/usr/share/myapp/logs/application.log]
>
> 15:38:33,900 |-ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] -
>   openFile(/usr/share/myapp/logs/application.log,true) call failed.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/myapp/logs/application.log
>   (No such file or directory)   at java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /usr/share/myapp/logs/application.log (No such file or directory)

Even though it gives errors the site does sorta start up and is reachable on port 9000 when I run the script manually.

So, my question: How do I get the package to work automatically just by running `sudo start myapp` ?